# Cant go to last week of month in calendar

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calendar

I can't seem to find a way to navigate to the last week of a month, meaning 24 is the last day i see this month March 2012 (in month view), when navigating to next month, first day is 1 whilst week 13 is completely skipped.

Any idea what that can be?

Here is what it looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot (or photo of the screen)?

Comment: How do I take a screenshot of my Droid?

Comment: @Shimmy there are many apps for that. Some needs rooted device, some doesn't. If you are unable to take screenshot using any app, shoot a photo of it using external cam..

Comment: @SachinShekhar ok u got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem.

I changed the density to a higher resolution. After resetting to system resolution, problem was solved.

I would still be glad to know if there is a solution that will allow me using the calendar at a high res. as well.